# Is there any way to run a script inside alredy existing infrastructre using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I  want to run a script using terraform inside an existing instance  on any cloud which is pre-created .The instance was created manually , is there any way to push my script to this instance and run it using terraform ?
if yes ,then How can i connect to the instance using terraform and push my script and run it ?

Comment: Generally, no. There isn't a good way to "push my script to this instance and run it using terraform". This is usually handled by some other orchestration software such as Ansible. You may have cases where you can do this at instance provision time with Terraform. But not for instances already existing. If you need to do this in Terraform you should clearly explain why since it isn't a typical use case.

Comment: hi @ Andy Shinn .I used null_resource to push our script or run a command on remote infra

Comment: Pratheesh you might be able to use null_resource to execute a script on ec2. However, terraform is ideal for provisioning of infrastructure and your requirement is to configure a server that is different and we have ansible, chef, puppet tool for that purpose.

Comment: @Mahattam ,i was trying to do the same job as ansible using terraform.

Answer (score 1):

I believe ansible is a better option to achieve this easily.

Refer the example give here - 
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `.tf` file and describe your already existing resource (e.g. VM) there
2. Import existing thing using [terraform import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html)
3. If this is a VM then add your script to remote machine using [file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/file.html) provisioner and run it using [remote-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html) - both steps are described in Terraform file, no manual changes needed
4. Run `terraform plan` to see if expected changes are ok, then `terraform apply` if plan was fine

Answer (score 0):

Terraform's core mission is to create, update, and destroy long-lived infrastructure objects. It is not generally concerned with the software running in the compute instances it deploys. Instead, it generally expects each object it is deploying to behave as a sort of specialized "appliance", either by being a managed service provided by your cloud vendor or because you've prepared your own machine image outside of Terraform that is designed to launch the relevant workload immediately when the system boots. Terraform then just provides the system with any configuration information required to find and interact with the surrounding infrastructure.

A less-ideal way to work with Terraform is to use its provisioners feature to do late customization of an image just after it's created, but [that's considered to be a last resort](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html#provisioners-are-a-last-resort) because Terraform's lifecycle is not designed to include strong support for such a workflow, and it will tend to require a lot more coupling between your main system and its orchestration layer.

Terraform has no mechanism intended for pushing arbitrary files into existing virtual machines. If your virtual machines need ongoing configuration maintenence after they've been created (by Terraform or otherwise) then that's a use-case for traditional configuration management software such as Ansible, Chef, Puppet, etc, rather than for Terraform.